# Passing MySql connection in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have tried putting a mysqli connection script into a php function that various php files can call to connect to the database. I have created the following function:

```
public function connectToDatabase() {

    $con = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);

    echo "<br><br>";

    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error();
    } else {
        echo "Connection successful";
    }

    return $con;
}
```

I then call that function from another file using (the above file has been included):

```
$con = connectToDatabase();
```

However, while the code in the top function works fine, passing the connection in the variable $con doesnt seem to work. It has occured to me that the connection is closing automatically when it reaches the return statement. Is this the case? If so, how can I stop that?

Many thanks

Comment: `connectToDatabase` !== `connectToDatabse`

Comment: [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are “undefined variable” errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: ...how embarrassing...

Comment: ok so I have edited the databAse typo, but still it doesnt work...?

Comment: @BenThompson First, try echoing out the value of the variable `$con` from that file itself. Then, find whether including the file throws any error. If you are in doubt, post the lines you used to include the php file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While your issue has been answered in the comments, better to structure your connection as a Singleton class, so you're not opening multiple instances of your connection throughout your code:

```
class DatabaseConnection {

    const HOST     = 'localhost';
    const USERNAME = 'not_root';
    const PASSWORD = 'not_blank';
    const NAME     = 'your_db';

    private static $_instance;

    // Private constructor prevents instantiation
    private function __construct() {
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!self::$_instance) {
            self::$_instance = mysqli_connect(self::HOST, self::USERNAME, self::PASSWORD, self::NAME);
            if (mysqli_connect_errno(self::$_instance)) {
                throw new Exception("Failed to connect to MySQL:" . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

Then, call it like this:

```
try {
    $con = DatabaseConnection::getInstance();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Handle exception
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: interesting...if I use a singleton, do I need to create a new object before calling the getInstance() function?

Comment: No.  A singleton works statically, so you never need to instantiate it.